# What rocket league preset cars are exclusively available on Xbox?

Tags: xbox-one, rocket-league

I want to get all of the free cars. 
I know that some cars are platform exclusives - for example Samus Gunship for Switch.

What are the exclusive Xbox cars?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Rocket League Wikia](http://rocketleague.wikia.com/wiki/Vehicles):

> The PlayStation 4, Xbox One and Nintendo Switch versions also include
>   console-exclusive unlockable Battle-Cars (Sweet Tooth for the
>   PlayStation 4 version; **Hogsticker and Armadillo for the Xbox One
>   version**; Mario NSR, Luigi NSR and Samus' Gunship for the Nintendo
>   Switch Version). Bodies record the number of matches won while
>   equipped.